# fputcsv(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, fputcsv

I have the following code;

I am trying to generate csv with following code but it is giving me error:

**fputcsv(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource**

```
// CSV column headings
$csv = Array
(
    "Card #, 
     Value of Card, 
     Current balance, 
     Amount used, 
     Transaction #,
     Transaction Date, 
     Ship To Name, 
     Ship To Address 1, 
     Ship To Address 2,
     Ship To Address 3, 
     Customer Telephone");

$csv [] = "2831013003939663, 
           0, 
           $1223.71, 
           $155.69,
           NULL,
           02-04-19_05:49:06,
           Demo demo,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           8108749624";


    $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
    foreach ($csv as $line)
      {
        fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
      }
    fclose($file);
```

I am getting outputin  following manner for in debug:

**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Card #,Value of Card,Current balance,Amount used,Transaction #,Transaction Date,Ship To Name,Ship To Address 1,Ship To Address 2,Ship To Address 3,Customer Telephone
    [1] => 2831013003939663,0,$1223.71,$155.69,-,02-04-19_05:49:06,Demo demo,-,-,-,8108749624
)
```

**

I dont understand What wrong is going with above code here?

Comment: Have you checked that the call to `fopen` succeeded?

Comment: yes.. it is giving me the value in debug "Resource id #1687"  and file "contacts.csv" created at location correctly

Answer (score 10):

Just another note that this can happen, when you are looping to put data in CSV and you perform `fclose()` in the loop instead of doing it at the end.

For example :

```php
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    foreach(...){
    
        // Do something in the loop
        // Put Data in csv
        fputcsv($handle, $data);
    
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Now, in this case, the second iteration will not have the $handle stream because it was already closed at the end of the first iteration.

It should be like this :

```php
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    foreach(...){
    
        // Do something in the loop
        // Put Data in csv
        fputcsv($handle, $data);
    
    }
    
    // Closing after all actions on this CSV are done
    fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
$arr=array("Card #,Value of Card,Current balance,Amount used,Transaction #,Transaction Date,Ship To Name,Ship To Address 1,Ship To Address 2,Ship To Address 3, Customer Telephone",
       "2831013003939663,0,$1259.64,$119.76,NULL,02-04-19_05:49:06,Demo demo,NULL,NULL, NULL,8108749624");


$filename = "contacts.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

foreach($arr as $row) {
     $exploded_row=explode(',',$row);
     fputcsv($handle,$exploded_row);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: No its not working for me. please check  i have updated my question with debug output

Comment: thanks, its working for me.. everything was correct ... the only mistake in my code was array formation in the correct way...  which was clarified from your answer... my remaining code I have put same as before.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it